# Why isn't my delete statement working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-delete, sqlcommand

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM dbo.DisplayData"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I have the following delete statement at the moment, it's throwing an error at me when it's executed "Incorrect syntax near '*'".

What I'm trying to do is delete all the rows in the DisplayData table then I insert new data, as far as I was aware this was the correct syntax for a SQL delete all statement?

I've looked around online and can't find anything that says my syntax is incorrect. And I can't find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `*`..

Comment: @CrushSundae Perfect thanks, but, at the risk of sounding like an idiot... why don't  I need a '*' I thought this was what you needed to reference all rows/columns that fit the query?

Comment: That was used for `SELECT` statements. I advise you to read first the basic fundamentals of querying. :)

Comment: Here was me thinking I knew them lol,  as far as I remember that's how I was taught in first year using SQL-Server, checked w3Schools and it has the same thing there... oh well, fixed now, thanks

Comment: I knew it because I did the same thing before when I was just starting. lol.

Comment: To be fair, some SQL systems do allow `DELETE *`, but since you delete an entire row, specifying columns is not necessary, and so `*` has no effect on the statement.

Comment: @DStanley That's the explanation I was looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM dbo.DisplayData"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

OR

```
cmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE dbo.DisplayData"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Note: truncate will reset the auto increment

Here's a good [article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/delete-all-data-mysql/) about it.

Comment: Be careful when you are using `TRUNCATE`. This will reset all the seeds of your auto-increment IDs. This will totally **RESET** your table.

Comment: This is probably what the OP really needs.  `TRUNCATE` is faster than `DELETE`; it doesn't log the individual transactions; and it doesn't call delete triggers.